Click button on loading inside YouTube iFrame API using JavaScript
I need to automatically click on the "Playlist Menu Button" when an embedded YouTube playlist is first loaded (in a iFrame). I understand that this needs to be done using the YouTube iFrame API and have that script working (have installed Google's Example 1 on their API documentation which enables different border colours depending on status).
YouTube have given the button I want to click the classes "ytp-playlist-menu-button ytp-button".
I was hoping that adding document.getElementsByClassName("ytp-playlist-menu-button").click(); to the code below would work:
  tag.id = 'iframe-demo';
  tag.src = 'https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api';
  var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
  firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

  var player;
  function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
    player = new YT.Player('player_2', {
        events: {
          'onReady': onPlayerReady,
          'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
        }
    });
  }
  function onPlayerReady(event) {
    document.getElementById('player_2').style.borderColor = '#FF6D00';
    document.getElementsByClassName("ytp-playlist-menu-button").click();
  }

but it doesn't!
Can anyone let me know what it should be to have the button clicked on when the iframe loads? You can view the page where I'm trying to do this here

If the page in the iframe is from another domain, then you can not interact with it like this.

This question is similar to: YouTube iframe API: how do I control an iframe player that's already in the HTML?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

I find it hard to believe that Google don't offer a facility to show the playlist menu when embedding a YouTube playlist! I was told when I first asked a question about this that it can be achieved using the Youtube iFrame API but you're now suggesting this is not possible. Google say they monitor StackOverflow questions that have the tage youtube-iframe-api - if Google does see this question: please can you explain how to show the playlist menu when first loading an embedded iframe? (fyi: to do this manually you press on the button with classes ytp-playlist-menu-button & ytp-button)

I said it wasn’t possible the way you are doing it. Having just had a look at the docs that you linked, the Google API offers player.getIframe() which is maybe what you’re after.

Appreciate your help here @DavidBradshaw but can't find any examples of using player.getIframe() Google says player.getIframe():Object can be used to access & modify DOM nodes but nothing further on how to construct the line or an example as to how it's used in their API documentation? Can you give me a hint as to how to do that? If the class for the button I want to click on is ytp-playlist-menu-button is it something like player.getIframe('ytp-playlist-menu-button'):Object - or should I be replacing Object with something? A bit lost with it at the moment but need to find a way

I have never used it, but it says it somehow returns the document object of the iframe. I’m not sure how that is even possible in JS. I would suggest doing console.dir(player.getIframe()) and seeing what it actually gives you.
